# Как добавить в базу данных по умолчание значение на кириллице?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

phpmyadmin выдает вот такую ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

База в кодировке utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Если на латинском добавлять, то все нормально, ошибки нет

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466872/why-cant-a-text-column-have-a-default-value-in-mysql

Comment: @Mike, это совсем не то

Comment: Вы уверены ? вот вы пишите что заменили text на varchar и это помогло. И там как раз речь что в mysql при определенных настройках бывают проблемы с дефаулт значениями у text

Answer (score 1):

Тип поля `TEXT` заменил `varchar(320)` и ошибка пропала, непонятно только с чем связано.